# Can I programmatically modify which UITableViewCell is selected?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

Is there a way to move the highlighted tableviewcell programatically.  If I wanted to highlight cell number 3 and then highlight cell number 4 instead, based on something the user did in the detail view of my split view controller, can I do this?

Is there a way I can get the indexpath for the row two below one that I have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via the [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableView) `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` method.

In terms of getting the "next" row from the `indexPath`, you can simply use the `indexPath.row` property (as supplied from your [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate)'s `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` method) as the basis for the selected row.

Comment: @Rossi No problems. Happy coding. :-)